# Multiple nested 'for' loops without knowing the number of 'for' loops

Tags: c++, recursion, nested-loops

How would I write *n* nested *for* loops without knowing what *n* is?

For example, how would I write the following using recursion or another method?

```
for (int i = 0; cond1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; cond2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; cond3; k++)
        ...
            for (int l = 0; cond_N; l++) {
                if (.....) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, there are *n* loops with some condition (not necessarily the same condition for each variable) and I'm not sure how to transform this into code using recursion without knowing what *n* is.

Comment: do you mean ```without knowing n``` in compile time?

Comment: How do you teat for N different conditions without knowing N?

Comment: You could do it with a vector where each element contained the state information associated with each nested loop.

Comment: N is known at run time. Also, could you please let me know what mean by the state information?

for (int i = 0; cond1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; cond2; j++){
        for (int k = 0; cond3; k++)
            ...
            for (int l = 0; cond_N; l++){
                if (.....) break;
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @shshshsh, it will be easier if you say what exactly do you want to implement through this way, and how this cond's realted each other

Comment: Then there's the question of why you don't want recursion.

Comment: Once again. If N is only known at run time, what "cond_1, cond_2, ..., cond_N" could *possibly* mean? How do you write down "cond_N" without knowing N? You can have "cond(1), cond(2), ..., cond(N)" where "cond" is a function, but "cond_N" just makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you need this for? Right now I find it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. 
Otherwise, some sort of state-machine maybe. Or simply a vector of lambdas and then you loop while vector is not empty, pop a lambda and loop while it yields `true` (but ofc the condition needs to change at some point, or you'll loop forever).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you’re trying to do? `cond` provides the N different conditions (i.e., a loop-variable-dependent bool function) and `foo` introduces recursion:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool cond(int cond_which, int current_loop_variable) {
    switch (cond_which) {
    case 0:
        return current_loop_variable < 5;
    case 1:
        return current_loop_variable < 3;

    /* More... can be a hell of complicated, related with states, whatever */

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

void foo(int we_may_call_it_the_meta_loop_variable) {
    for (int i = 0; cond(we_may_call_it_the_meta_loop_variable, i); ++i) {
        foo(we_may_call_it_the_meta_loop_variable + 1);
        std::cout << "in loop " << we_may_call_it_the_meta_loop_variable << ", i = " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly this is not an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is one application to this question. For example, find the bar cutting combinations of 3 bar lengths. So that the waste should not be longer than 1' (2.5 cm) after cutting in the 20' (50 cm) length rebar.

So, I used three nested loops, because there are three bar cuts. If I have 50 bar cuts, then I will use 50 nested loops. So, this is how can we rewrite it using recursion.

[Relative question in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089153/something-better-than-many-nested-for-loops)

[image: Code and correct answer for the given data]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77887607/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements (reverse engineered from the question):

- the body of the loop knows which iteration it is for self and all parents
- the number of loops is between 0 and at least hundreds
- memory allocation isn't a problem, i.e., no attempt at limiting it via compartmentalization is required
- manual termination of the current (but not parent) loop is available
- loop counters are integers and count upwards from zero
- no code is executed, except in the leaf loop
- recursion is not compulsory

Here's a stab to try to get the idea across, and I will try compiling it upon interest. Again: **it does not work as currently is**.

```
using Counter = int;
using State = std::vector<Counter>;
using Condition = std::function<bool(const State &)>;
using Action = std::function<void(const State &)>;

void run(const std::vector<Condition> & conditions, Action action)
{
    std::vector<Counter> state(conditions.size(), 0);
    unsigned depth{};
    while(depth < conditions.size() && ! conditions[conditions.size()-1-depth])
    {
        if(conditions[conditions.size()-1-depth](state))
        {
            action(state);
        }
        else
        {
            // Go up the stack of loops.
            while(depth++ < state.size())
            {
                state[state.size()-1-depth] = 0
                ++state[state.size()-2-depth];
            }
        }
    }
}
```